# Can not get MSMQ Com to find my Queue

Tags: c#, interop, msmq, com-interop

I am trying to get a count of messages in my MSMQ.  I have found this code on the internet (many times):

```
// setup the queue management COM stuff
MSMQManagement _queueManager = new MSMQManagement();

object machine = "MyLaptopComputer";
object path = @"DIRECT=OS:MyLaptopComputer\PRIVATE$\MyQueue";

_queueManager.Init(ref machine, ref path);

Console.WriteLine(_queueManager.MessageCount);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_queueManager);
```

Every time I get to `_queueManager.Init` it fails with this error:

> The queue path name specified is invalid.

I have checked (and double checked) my queue name to see if that is wrong.  I have tried different queues, different machines, running remote, running local... Nothing works.

I have also tried variations on the code above.  For example I have tried:

```
_queueManager.Init("MyLaptopComputer", @"DIRECT=OS:MyLaptopComputer\PRIVATE$\MyQueue");
```

The queues are used with NServiceBus and function just fine when I use NServiceBus to access them.

Does anyone have an Idea on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried using "localhost" or "." in your path, instead of your explicit computer name?

Comment: @SeanH I had tried ".".  However, I should have tried just a bit longer before giving up.  See my answer below to see my working change.

Comment: Why are you using the COM classes when there is a perfectly good Api within the. Net framework since you are using c#?

Comment: @Kjell-ÅkeGafvelin - the .Net Framework does not support getting a count of messages.  (Unless you are willing to read all the messages first.  If you have over 10,000 messages it is quite a bit of overhead to load them all just to get a count.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the error you're getting is a little misguiding. [`MSMQManagement.Init`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes 3 parameters. They're all optional which is why in other languages (like VB) you'll sometimes see it called with only 2 parameters.

There is a [CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22847/Accessing-Outgoing-Message-Queues-MSMQ) that shows how to do what you're doing in C#:

```
private int GetMessageCount(string queueName)
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {

        MSMQ.MSMQManagement mgmt = new MSMQ.MSMQManagement();
        MSMQ.MSMQOutgoingQueueManagement outgoing;
        String s = "YOURPCNAME";
        Object ss = (Object)s;
        String pathName = queueName;
        Object pn = (Object)pathName;
        String format = null;
        Object f = (Object)format;

        mgmt.Init(ref ss , ref f, ref pn);

        outgoing = (MSMQ.MSMQOutgoingQueueManagement)mgmt;
        count = outgoing.MessageCount;

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
    }
    return count;
}
```

It might provide a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a combination of issues.  The biggest being that I needed to use FormatName not path name.

```
_queueManager.Init("MyComputer", null, @"DIRECT=OS:MyComputer\PRIVATE$\MyQueue");
```

Also, it will throw an exception if the queue is empty...

Got to love COM interfaces. :)